# Where can I find a blank outline of Silk Road routes?

Tags: geography

I am looking for a blank outline map of Silk Road routes from the Pacific to Europe including African and European cities and outposts. Ideally the route(s) will be pre-drawn. Students label cities/outposts. Current sources insufficient.

Comment: This seems very specific. Have you considered making your own? It would probably be much less work than scouring the internet for the perfect rendition for your purposes.

Comment: Consider taking a labeled map and removing the labels in your favorite image editor?

Comment: Here is an ArcGIS online layer with the data you want.  You can turn various layers on and off and change the basemap if you want.  https://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?webmap=55399ae83b1f43e1a9d3d7f5e946da23

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this image might be interesting:
https://www.visualcapitalist.com/medieval-trade-route-map/

[image]

It represents XI and XII centuries, and covers most of Asia, Africa and Europe. The map includes a list of sources that you might try to follow.

From the comment below:

> [Downloadable hi-res here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjPUP.jpg)

Comment: Downloadable hi-res here: https://i.imgur.com/MsXaOdV.jpg